# Numpy array indexing unexpected behavior and shape

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I was getting unexpected numpy array shape while playing with indexing.

Considering the following example, we have a shape `1000x100x25x25x3` numpy array and we index it with two numpy array `ind1` and `ind2`. Why the shape of the resulting array `d1` and `d2` are different?

Also, why the shape of `d1` is `256x25x25x3`?

```
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randn(1000, 100, 25, 25, 3)

ind1 = np.random.randint(0, 1000, size=(256)).astype(int)
ind2 = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(256)).astype(int)

d1 = data[ind1, ind2]
d2 = data[ind1][:, ind2]

print(d1.shape, d2.shape)
# (256, 25, 25, 3) (256, 256, 25, 25, 3)
```

Comment: `d2` gets a block.  `d1` contains the diagonal elements of that block (check that for me).  With 2 arrays of indices, `numpy` "broadcasts" them against each other.  This is called `advanced indexing`.

Comment: oh I see, never heard about this before. I just googled `advanced indexing` and tried to learn it, so it means `d1` is essentially indexed by paired element from `ind1` and `ind2`. And yes, `d1` contains the diagonal elements of `d2`. TY!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @hpaulj for super helpful comments.

It turns this behavior is called `advanced indexing`, as a result, `d1` contains the diagonal elements of `d2`.

I found [this tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/indexing-in-numpy/) explains the concept quite well.